# using for loop or lapply to append to rows of data frame in r from the ttest

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, datatable

Alright I have checked the internet, and I am still creating a data frame of replicated lines.
I have a for loop that is creating the welch t-test results, I have saved the values like such:

```
gene <- biomarkers$Symbol
pval <- ttest$p.value
tstat <- ttest$statistic
```

I tried  to iterate with the for loop to add the results to a data frame which created at the start of the chunk

```
df2 <- data.frame(pathol=(character()),
                  genes=character(),
                 p_value=character(), 
                 t_stat=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 


for (gene in biomarkers$Symbol) {
  print(gene)
  ddat <- degs[degs$Symbol== gene & degs$pathol=="mitosis",]
  ttest <- t.test(logFC ~ value, data = ddat)
  print (ttest)
  df2[nrow(df2) + 1,] #(this added the 10 genes only to the rows, not to the column)
```

then I realised I need to use lapply...which I tried this:

```
prova <- lapply(biomarkers$Symbol, function(gene) {
  append =  (gene)
  #ttest <- t.test(logFC ~ value, data = ddat)

  })

do.call(rbind, prova)
```

this created a list of the ten genes, however when I uncomment the variable 'ttest', it just adds a list of:

```
 [1,] "logFC by value"
 [2,] "logFC by value"
 [3,] "logFC by value"
 [4,] "logFC by value"
 [5,] "logFC by value"
 [6,] "logFC by value"
 [7,] "logFC by value"
 [8,] "logFC by value"
 [9,] "logFC by value"
[10,] "logFC by value"
```

I would like to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

| pathol | genes | p_value | t_stat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mitosis | PBK | 0.05 | 000.4 |
| mitosis | PLK4 | 0.02 | 000.9 |

#the gene will be the same for all of the rows.
any help would be great!

EDIT

dput output:

```
dput(head(ddat))
structure(list(experiment = c("FP001RO_15_HI", "FP001RO_15_HI", 
"FP001RO_15_HI", "FP001RO_15_LOW", "FP001RO_15_LOW", "FP001RO_15_LOW"
), Human.Gene.entrezID = c("57405", "57405", "57405", "57405", 
"57405", "57405"), Symbol = c("SPC25", "SPC25", "SPC25", "SPC25", 
"SPC25", "SPC25"), description = c("SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex", 
"SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex", "SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex", 
"SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex", "SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex", 
"SPC25 component of NDC80 kinetochore complex"), score = c(3.867, 
3.867, 3.867, 3.867, 3.867, 3.867), type = c("WGGNC", "WGGNC", 
"WGGNC", "WGGNC", "WGGNC", "WGGNC"), pathol = c("mitosis", "mitosis", 
"mitosis", "mitosis", "mitosis", "mitosis"), Probeid = c("295661_at", 
"295661_at", "295661_at", "295661_at", "295661_at", "295661_at"
), logFC = c(-0.0641349806730976, -0.0641349806730976, -0.0641349806730976, 
-0.0324566291924587, -0.0324566291924587, -0.0324566291924587
), AveExpr = c(4.1541958195567, 4.1541958195567, 4.1541958195567, 
4.17003499529702, 4.17003499529702, 4.17003499529702), t = c(-0.567682269120301, 
-0.567682269120301, -0.567682269120301, -0.214562465957216, -0.214562465957216, 
-0.214562465957216), P.Value = c(0.580865708246137, 0.580865708246137, 
0.580865708246137, 0.833648126277364, 0.833648126277364, 0.833648126277364
), adj.P.Val = c(0.828914361133465, 0.828914361133465, 0.828914361133465, 
0.999594589241814, 0.999594589241814, 0.999594589241814), B = c(-6.4683360535952, 
-6.4683360535952, -6.4683360535952, -5.45944975240508, -5.45944975240508, 
-5.45944975240508), cpd = c("FP001RO", "FP001RO", "FP001RO", 
"FP001RO", "FP001RO", "FP001RO"), time = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15), dose = c("HI", "HI", "HI", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW"), entrezgene_rat = c(295661, 
295661, 295661, 295661, 295661, 295661), external_gene_name_rat = c("Spc25", 
"Spc25", "Spc25", "Spc25", "Spc25", "Spc25"), external_gene_name_human = c("SPC25", 
"SPC25", "SPC25", "SPC25", "SPC25", "SPC25"), entrezGene_probes_human = c("57405_at", 
"57405_at", "57405_at", "57405_at", "57405_at", "57405_at"), 
    inMap_human_withGrey = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), inMap_rat_withGrey = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), variable = structure(c(11L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L), .Label = c("Necrosis1", "Necrosis2", "Necrosis3", 
    "hyperpl1", "hyperpl2", "hyperpl3", "fibrosis", "hypertrophy1", 
    "hypertrophy2", "mitosis1", "mitosis2", "mitosis3", "vacuolation1", 
    "vacuolation2", "vacuolation3"), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    pathology = c("mitosis", "mitosis", "mitosis", "mitosis", 
    "mitosis", "mitosis")), row.names = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 55L, 
56L, 57L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput of gene

```
dput(biomarkers$Symbol)
c("PBK", "PLK4", "CDKN3", "CDCA3", "PRC1", "CDK1", "TCF19", "SHCBP1", 
"CENPK", "SPC25")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: In the `lapply`, where is `gene` used ? The formula seems static `ttest <- t.test(logFC ~ value, data = ddat)`

Comment: `structure(list(pathol = character(0), genes = character(0), p_value = character(0), 
    t_stat = character(0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0))`

Comment: I meant the ddat and biomarkers$Symbol

Comment: `gene` is `biomarkers$Symbol` from another data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
prova <- lapply(biomarkers$Symbol, function(gene) {
      ddat <- subset(degs, Symbol == gene & pathol =="mitosis")
      fmla <- reformulate('value', response = 'logFC')
      if(nlevels(droplevels(ddat$val)) >=2) {
          ttest <- t.test(fmla, data = ddat)
          data.frame(pathol = 'mitosis', genes = gene,
                  p_value = ttest$p.value, t_stat = ttest$statistic)
        } else NULL
     

  })
names(prova) <- biomarkers$Symbol
out <- do.call(rbind, prova)
```

Comment: Prova should be annotated with a gene column so we know which gene goes to which test

Comment: strange, it gives me this error: `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'PBK' not found`

Comment: @FrancescaC I just noticed your dput.  The `gene` are  not column names in the 'ddat'.  Do you want to subset the ddat with values from `gene`?

Comment: @FrancescaC I meant `prova <- lapply(biomarkers$Symbol, function(gene) {dsub <- subset(ddat, Symbol == gene & pathol =="mitosis");
      fmla <- reformulate('value', response = 'logFC');
      ttest <- t.test(fmla, data = dsub);
      ttest

  })`

Comment: no, it isn't I just assigned it that from the biomarkers data frame which is different from the ddat data frame. however in the ddat data frame the column "Symbol" is the same, but its not the "top 10 genes" like subsetted from the biomarkers dataframe of 10

Comment: Okay I tried that too: `Error in t.test.formula(fmla, data = dsub) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels`

Comment: @FrancescaC it is very confusing about your code.  I assumed `degs` as `ddat` dput from your code `ddat <- degs[degs$Symbol== gene & degs$pathol=="mitosis",]`

Comment: the error lies with the line `ttest <- t.test(fmla, data = dsub)`. hmm, ddat is a subset based on the top ten biomarkers.

Comment: @FrancescaC try the update.  I changed it to `degs` and `ddat`.  which I can't test

Comment: it seems to work! however how can I transfer it to a data frame? it isa list of 10 with each value in each column, I would also need to add a column to identify the gene itself, mitosis

Comment: I think it is only printing the t stat, not the p value as well however!

Comment: @FrancescaC try the update

Comment: ok I did a dput, and it does show `list(PBK = structure(list(statistic = c(t = -2.42287303674849), 
    parameter = c(df = 18.1390707140727), p.value = 0.026078130209346, 
    conf.int = structure(c(-0.540133451446708, -0.0385880302604682
    ), conf.level = 0.95), estimate = c(mean in group 0= 0.186200209654921, 
    mean in group 1 = 0.47556095050851), null.value = c(difference in means between group 0 and group 1 = 0), 
    stderr = 0.119428767609677, alternative = "two.sided", method = "Welch Two Sample t-test", 
    data.name = "logFC by value"), class = "htest"), PLK4 =`

Comment: But how can I extract just the stats and the gene?

Comment: @FrancescaC perhaps your page didn't refresh.  I already updated with `data.frame(pathol = 'mitosis', genes = gene,
                  p_value = ttest$p.value, t_stat = ttest$statistic)`

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to your question, remember to perform multiple hypothesis testing correction when doing lots of tests at once.

Working off of akrun's answer, here's BH correction:

```
ord = order(prova$p.value)
prova$fdr = prova$p.value*nrow(prova)/ord
```

This will reduce the number of false positives.

Comment: Hmph! I didn't know about this.... thanks! how do you know it is necessary?

Comment: The chance of any t-test being wrong when comparing p-value to 0.05 is 5%. When doing 2 tests, the chance of at least 1 being wrong is greater than 5% and so on with larger datasets is the simplest way to think of it. You should read into this more, it's some pretty interesting stuff lol